# how to uncheck checbox while returning from another activity

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-activity, return

I've tried to make it by onResume but it didn't work, also I tried to make it by startActivityForResult and still nothing. I want to make it as simple as it can be. Should I do something else in my OnResume? All answers, suggestions, clues are wellcome. If you don't know how to do it, pop up thread. Thank you for your time.

In my Adapter i've got class:

```
class ViewHolder {
TextView tvNazwaT;
TextView tvCenaT;
ImageView ivTowar;
CheckBox chb_czy_zamowic;
 }
```

There is my `checkbox` which I want to change after on `button` click(click cause returning to main `activity` where `checkbox` is just displayed in my gridview).

All logic form Adapter (actually in `getView` method) for checkbox is here:

```
view.chb_czy_zamowic
.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(
                                                                                           final CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
display dialog; }
```

Here is return button from NextActivity:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

In my MainActivity i've tryied something in onResume method but I cant get acces to it in any known way.

```
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow.clear();
if (MainActivity.lista_wybranych_towarow.isEmpty()) {
b_zatwierdz.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

So I tried this in my Adapter:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
final Intent intent = 
new Intent(getContext(),  Zatwierdz.class);
context.startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}


});
```

In my MainActivity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
final int resultCode, final   Intent data) {
switch (requestCode) {
case 1:
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chb_czy_zamowic);
cb.setChecked(false);

break;
}
}
```

It also didn't work out.

Here is my all code:

```
**MainActivity:** http://pastebin.com/DUz6GWbw  
**Adapter:** http://pastebin.com/jHWqBaf0   
**DefaultActivity:** http://pastebin.com/1VgEAZhZ
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have some underlaying data under your grid adapter. When you leave activity, remember checked position in some variable in activity scope, or simply mark it as checked in your data structure. When you came back from another activity, undo that change and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

Comment: yes,but the problem is that the checkbox is avialble only in adapter